# Trouble with TransitionFrame

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am doing a WP7 application. My problem is transition frame is not accepting. i got the error

"Error  1   The type or namespace name 'TransitionFrame' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\Resources\Windows-phone\Appcity\Appcity.Application\App.xaml.cs  108 28  Appcity.Application".

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks..

Code in App.xaml.cs is

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        //RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
       RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
        RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you reference windows phone toolkit's dll in your project?

Comment: @abhinav: I am new to WP7. I think the reference is there. I have added the dll file to lib. In the reference folder of my application I can see Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the references in the "Solution Explorer" (your project), click on "Add reference" then browse to the Toolkit's dll and add it.
That should fix it.
See [this page](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide)

Comment: When I browse and add it says "A reference to the component "Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" already exists in the project". There is any other toolkit?

Comment: Seems like you already have it referenced, could you try removing the reference and following the steps provided in the link(answer).